# How do I count time in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I don't want to set up a timer that "fires" (and does something) after a certain amount of time has passed.

Therefore, I'm not interested in the `NSTimer` class and its methods.

All I'm interested in is counting the time that passes by *while*, for example, some while-loop is executing. I could use `NSDate` as follows I guess :

```
NSDate currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

while(someConditionIsTrue)
{
    // executing..
}

timeElapsed = [self timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];

NSLog(@"time elapsed was: %i", timeElapsed);
```

However, if I understand correctly, `timeIntervalSinceDate:` can only count seconds.

Is there a way I can count the time that is passing by in *milliseconds*?

In other words, **what is the smallest unit I can count passing time in and how ?**

Comment: If you're looking for an easy way to time your code, http://eng.pulse.me/line-by-line-speed-analysis-for-ios-apps/ may be what you want.

Comment: It number of seconds, but it's floating point, so you get, effectively, milliseconds. Use `%f` in your format string.

Comment: It's a little better to do `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate]` twice, once when starting and once when done, and subtract the first value from the second.  Doesn't unnecessarily create an NSDate object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second approach is correct. Save the current date in an `NSDate` object and use `timeIntervalSinceDate:` to get the passed time since then. The result will be of type `NSTimeInterval` which is a floating point number. It specifies time differences in seconds, but since it's a floating point number it can store fractions of a second as well.

> NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields
>   sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.

Comment: I hadn't realized it returns a floating point number. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Look at [CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001452-CH201-F12326)

```
CFAbsoluteTime before = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CFAbsoluteTime after = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

Comment: This seems simpler for situations like this, although `NSDate` will work too

Comment: Actually, `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` probably maps directly to CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent, since they return the same value.